# htaccess - adding www redirect to current rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file and would like to also add redirection of non-www pages to the www equivalent:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried the following but would get a 500 error when trying to access anything but the root of the domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what does "freak out" look like?  what was the example code you tried?

Comment: IMHO looks the .htaccess file very nice. There are no errors.

Comment: added clarification to my question. thanks!

Comment: You may need to set the rewritebase direct after activating. I never had the idea to set it later.

Comment: @alfasin the if Tags should prevent 500 errors

Comment: Seems correct to me. I would try to not use `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable - just try to hardcode the whole hostname

Answer (score 0):

These lines work for me:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^morley\.cambs\.sch\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.morley\.cambs\.sch\.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have index.php file in your root directory.